# How to call non-x from a function within ave?

Tags: r, function, data.table

I have some data, for which I'd like to calculate total 'data' for all of the rows with the same ID minus the total 'data' for all the rows which don't share the same ID. At the moment I've figured out the first part (see code), but not the second part. Does anyone know how to call all non-x in a function within ave?

Example data:

```
 group_ID_dets <- data.table("group_ID" = rep(c(1,2), 2), "n_IDS" = 1:4, "data"= c(1,5,10,100))
```

My code for part 1:

```
 group_ID_dets$totals <- ave(group_ID_dets$data, group_ID_dets$group_ID, FUN = function(x) sum(x))
```

What I'd like to have as an output:

```
   group_ID n_IDS data totals
1:        1     1    1      0
2:        2     2    5     94
3:        1     3   10      0
4:        2     4  100     94
```

Comment: If it is a data.table, why not use data.table methods

Comment: Sorry I don't know much about data table methods. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Should `totals` not be `11-105 = -94` instead of zero, for `group_id` equal to 1

Comment: apologies, I forgot to say that I don't allow minus values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty sloppy, but using the way data table calculates the j expression, you can do the following:

```
group_ID_dets[, .(n_IDS, data, totals = max(c(2* sum(data) - sum(group_ID_dets$data), 0))), by = group_ID]
```

This uses `DT[i, j, by]` format, where the j expression is

```
.(n_IDS, data, totals = max(c(2* sum(data) - sum(group_ID_dets$data), 0)))
```

The j expression says we're going to include the n_IDS column, and the data column, and then we're going to calculate a totals column grouped by the group_ID column.

data.table evaluation is on grouped variables, but we can use data.frame extraction to pull the total for an entire column and get out of the grouping. So `sum(group_ID_dets$data)` still evaluates to the entire sum. We can then use the following equality:  a - sum(b, c, ...) =  a + a -( a + sum(b, c, ...)) = 2*a - sum(a, b, c, ...). We kept negative values as 0s, per your desired output.

```
   group_ID n_IDS data totals
1:        1     1    1      0
2:        1     3   10      0
3:        2     2    5     94
4:        2     4  100     94
```

Comment: great thanks! Works, but going to take me a while to figure out how!

Comment: You're welcome! I edited it to explain it a bit better.